# Exception: ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "..." for read

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I am trying to import .DMP file via SQL developer I am getting this error

```
Exception: ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/home/oracle/Desktop/dump/vahe.DMP" for read
```

dump directory  and vahe.dmp file have read and write permission. [image]

I use Database App Development VM.
how can I fix this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the permissions on the vahe.DMP.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have found the problem, it seams that i have misspelled the file name I have typed "vahe.DMP" instead of "vahe.dmp"( in lower case.)

Comment: instead of saying that file does not exist oracle gave me the wrong error message.

Comment: @user1321466 Congratulation for having solved your issue yourself. According to your first comment, I vote to close as _"that can no longer be reproduced"_ and _"a simple typographical error."_

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I thought that I can remove this question but then thought that someone might have same issue and decided to leave it. Sure you can close this question if it's right thing to do. Thank you.!!

Comment: @user1321466 Don't hesitate to close/delete yourself if you can. Unless you think this could be useful as future reference for other visitors: in that later case, you should post yourself the solution as an _answer_. Mentioning, for example that ORA-31640 is both for _wrong permission on the file_ as well as for _unreachable file_ (permission on some folder of the path) as well as _missing file_. That being said, as this is only a typo... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Well I found the problem. Actually I had type error. I have typo "vahe.DMP" instead of "vahe.dmp"(in lower case ). I think error message is not good one, because it should clearly say that file does not exist instead of saying "unable to open dump file ''  for read"  (IMHO)

Thanks everybody who tried  to help me.

Comment: The error message is as accurate as it possibly could be, I'd say. The oracle process can't tell whether the file exists or not - all it can say for sure is that it can't open it for reading. For example, the file *might* exist but not have the correct permission on it.

Comment: If the system find the file but can't open it, it should return a different error from the situation where the file could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error while importing DMP file shared from colleague.
error “ora-31640 unable to open dump file for read”
By creating new user with same name and password which was used while creating DMP file, and used this user for connect and importing, it resolved this error.

I was importing the data using "Data Pump Import Wizard" in oracle 11g R2 server.